# Open VPN Android/IOS client does not route traffic

Tags: dns, routing, android, openvpn, ios

I have open vpn server running on a raspberrypi with debian jessie.
And it works fine with the open vpn client for windows.
But the same ovpn file configuration that works for windows 7 does not seem to work for Android or IOS. It connects but then it does not route any traffic. It can't resolve any domain. And I can't ping google's ip (for example).

My server config looks like this:

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun

ca      /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/ca.crt    # generated keys
cert    /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/server.crt
key     /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/server.key  # keep secret
dh      /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/dh2048.pem

server 10.9.8.0 255.255.255.0  # internal tun0 connection IP
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt

keepalive 10 120

#comp-lzo         # Compression - must be turned on at both end
persist-key
persist-tun


mssfix 1450
tun-mtu 1500
tun-mtu-extra 32

push "redirect-gateway"
push "dhcp-option DNS 10.9.8.1"
push "dhcp-option WINS 10.9.8.1"

status log/openvpn-status.log

verb 5  # verbose mode
client-to-client
```

I also tried to push google's dns (that didn't work for any of them):

```
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option WINS 8.8.8.8"
```

And my client config has inline certs and looks like this:

```
client
dev tun
port 1194
proto udp

remote somevpnserver.com 1194 
nobind

#comp-lzo
persist-key
persist-tun

mssfix 1450
tun-mtu 1500
tun-mtu-extra 32

push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"

verb 5

<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>

<cert>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</cert>

<key>
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
</key>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to get it working with part of what I found [here](https://wiki.debian.org/OpenVPN#TLS-enabled_VPN).

```
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
user nobody
group nogroup
```